# Why are most command-line CLASSPATHs ignored by Mac OS Java 14?

Tags: java, macos, command-line, classpath

I am trying to run Java at the command line in Mac OS Catalina (10.15.7). Everything works properly under Ubuntu 18.04.5, but fails under Mac OS. Here are the specs:

Mac OS Catalina (10.15.7):

```
$java --version
java 14 2020-03-17
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 14+36-1461)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 14+36-1461, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Ubuntu 18.04.5:

```
$java --version
openjdk version "14.0.2" 2020-07-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 14.0.2+12-46)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 14.0.2+12-46, mixed mode, sharing)
```

The Java that I am using under Ubuntu is just an OpenJDK Java 14, while the Java that I'm using under Mac appears to be whatever flavour of Java 14 ships with macOS. If I try to run a standard `HelloWorld.java` from the command line in Ubuntu 18, everything works:

```
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello, World!");
    }
}
```

Compile:

```
$javac ./HelloWorld.java
```

Run:

```
$java HelloWorld
Hello, World!
```

Specifying the CLASSPATH explicitly, using `-cp`, also works:

```
$java -cp /home/anton/Desktop HelloWorld
Hello, World!
```

However the above completely fails on the command line in Mac OS:

```
$java HelloWorld
Error: Could not find or load main class HelloWorld
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: HelloWorld
```

```
$java -cp /Users/anton/Desktop HelloWorld
Error: Could not find or load main class HelloWorld
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: HelloWorld
```

As far as I know, **the only way to fix this situation on Mac OS is to copy the HelloWorld.class file to the /Library/Java/Extensions folder.** Then, everything works as expected, as long as the CLASSPATH is set appropriately:

```
$sudo cp ./HelloWorld.class /Library/Java/Extensions/
$java -cp /Library/Java/Extensions HelloWorld
Hello, World!
```

Questions:

1. Is there a clean way to get the Mac OS Java 14 to accept `-cp <CLASSPATH>` settings for files outside of /Library/Java/Extensions ?
2. If the answer to 1) is "no", is there a recommended alternative Java installation that can be used on the Mac OS command line?

Thanks!

Comment: There is no java with modern macOS. You must have installed it yourself.

Comment: My understanding is that **all** Java implementations handle `-cp` the same way. Therefore, what you are seeing is due to the way Java has been installed on your Mac or the way that you are using it.  Unfortunately, it is impractical for us to "look inside" your Mac to figure out the real cause.

Answer (score 0):

I just did a quick test on my Mac:

```sh
ravn@freewifi z % java -version
openjdk version "14" 2020-03-17
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 14+36-1461)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 14+36-1461, mixed mode, sharing)
ravn@freewifi z % javac HelloWorld.java
ravn@freewifi z % java HelloWorld
Hello, World!
ravn@freewifi z % type java
java is /usr/bin/java
ravn@freewifi z % /usr/libexec/java_home -V
Matching Java Virtual Machines (6):
    14 (x86_64) "Oracle Corporation" - "OpenJDK 14" /Users/ravn/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-14/Contents/Home
...
ravn@freewifi z %
```

It looks like your Java is an Oracle JVM, where mine and your Ubuntu Java is an OpenJDK JVM and that might explain it.  Possible things to investigate:  Do you have a CLASSPATH variable?  Is your `java` command pointing to the system binary?  Is it properly configured to a suitable JVM?

Comment: Thanks Thorbjorn. The Java on my Mac that is causing this issue is found at:

`/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-14.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java`

I had a look at the /usr/bin/java and it had been overwitten to the following link:

`/usr/bin/java -> /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/java` 

Both of these Javas display the same behaviour with respect to classpaths. Perhaps you're right - OpenJDK Java might be the only way. I'll try it out.

Comment: @sabinc_777 No, you need to see where your `java` command points, not to where the pointing points, because you might have misconfigured something in the process (if you set the PATH variable without knowing exactly what you were doing for instance).

Comment: Sorry was typing too fast - see edit above

Comment: Please note that MY system works as you expected (and I've done quite a bit of Java development so I'm pretty sure that this is installed correctly).  Hence it is possible - now you just need to find out where you broke stuff.

Comment: @Thornbjorn I think the situation is becoming clearer. The Java at /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/.../java, which displays the same strange classpath behaviour, is explicitly mentioned in the [Java Development Guide for Mac](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Java/Conceptual/Java14Development/01-JavaOverview/JavaOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001883-SW1).

Comment: The above document mentions /Library/Java/Extensions folder as well. Reading this, it's possible that the problematic Java I describe might have been installed along with another Apple product (XCode, etc.) or some other application requiring a JRE. Nonetheless, I will try to install an OpenJDK Java on my Mac and point to that instead.

Comment: Note for future reference that the extensions mechanism is being deprecated and will go away  (this is because Oracle want each deployment to bring its own JVM instead of having a system wide one)